# Don't understand how variable I is getting assigned a value in a struct

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct S {
    S(int i): I(i) { }
    int & v () { return I; }
    private :
    int I;
};

S s1 (1);
int main() {

    cout << s1.v() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

And I get the output:

```
1
```

I am confused as  to how it is working. For example with `s1` it is calling the constructor `S(int i)` but how is it sub-classing `I` and calling its constructor when there is no `I` class and how is the private variable `I` getting assigned a number when there has been nothing assigned to it? Also, if `v()` returns `int&` (a reference therefore, I would think it would print out a memory location but it gives 1 consistently).

Sorry if this sounds stupid can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have multiple questions:

1. The struct is not subclassing `I`, it is simply using Initialization Lists to construct the I variable. The same could have been done with the constructor  `S(int i) { I = i;}`.
2. It is getting assigned in the constructor, see #1.
3. You are confusing references and pointers. References pretend to act like regular value passed numbers. Pointers, returning `int *` with a function such as `int * v () { return &I; }` would print out the address of the variable unless you dereference them with the * symbol. References automatically dereference themselves.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now except: why not just make the return type `int` any diff?

Comment: anon: When you return int&, you can change the value of the variable through the function. Like you can do `si.v() = 3`. This use was one of the main reasons for introducing references to the language.

Comment: It's not being assigned anywhere, the advantage of the ctor-initializer syntax is that it performs initialization not assignment.

Answer (score 3):

> how is it sub-classing I and calling its constructor when there is no I class and how is the private variable I getting assigned a number when there has been nothing assigned to it?

The syntax

```
S(int i): I(i) { }
```

means construct `S` by assigning the member `I` the value of the parameter `i`. You could implement it like this instead:

```
S(int i) { I = i; }
```

---

> if v() returns int& (a reference therefore, I would think it would print out a memory location but it gives 1 consistently).

The reference return by `v` is a reference to the member `I` of `s1`. As long as `s1` hasn't been deallocated the reference is valid. In your code `s1` it is a static variable that only is deallocated when the program exits.

Comment: The part after the colon is referred to as an initialization list.

Comment: @anon: Every type has a constructor. Even pointers.

Comment: `I` is not being assigned.  It is being initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is being subclassed. I recommend you pick up a good C++ book and read up a bit. A class (or struct) in C++ has access specifiers `public`, `protected` and `private`, which control the access level to everything following the specifier:

```
class A
{
  /* private by default */
public:
  /* public stuff */
private:
  /* private again */
};

struct B
{
  /* public by default */
private:
  /* private stuff */
public:
  /* public stuff again */
private:
  /* private stuff again */
};
```

Your class `S` simply contains a private member `int I` which is initialized to `1` by the constructor and then printed.

---

The syntax for inheritance is a colon in the class declaration:

```
class  Foo : public Bar,
             protected FooBase,
             private SomeHelper
{ /* ... */ };
```